# Find the area of the rhombus given its side length and sum of diagonals

Tags: geometry

How can we find the area of the rhombus with side length $a=5$ and sum of diagonals $d_1+d_2=14$.

I know one formulas for the area of rhombus ($h$ stands for height):
$$A=ah=\frac{d_1d_2}{2}$$
But I don't see how they can help us here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$\left(\dfrac{d_1}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{d_2}{2}\right)^2 = a^2$

so with $a=5$ and $d_1+d_2=14$ you have three equations and three unknowns

Comment: Everything here (except $h$, which you do not need) turns out to be an integer